# Neo4j with spring data - expose field marked with @GraphId

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I try to use neo4j with spring data @RepositoryRestResource, but in returned json there is no "id" field. How to change this behaviour?

Example output:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "movies" : [ {
      "name" : "movie1",
     },
   ...
}
```

My entity:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Movie {

    @GraphId
    Long id;

    String name;

    // getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

My repo:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "movies", path = "movies")
public interface MovieRepo extends GraphRepository<Movie> { }
```

Comment: What version of SDN and SR-REST are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is a default setting for Spring Data REST. Configuration listed below helped, id is visible in JSON.

```
@Component
public class SpringDataRestCustomization extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        config.exposeIdsFor(Movie.class);
    }
}
```

I've noticed also that @RestController works differently and always prints id, no matter if it's or not exposed in the config, probably because it's not part of the Spring Data REST package.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to reconsider exposing your Neo4j-based id's in your REST responses... there is perhaps a reason why the SDR creators do not include the entity's id by default.

In the case of Neo4j and from an application view, exposing and using Neo4j internal id’s is safe, in that nothing in your application will break by using them.

That said, Neo4j internal id’s are recycled, by which I mean if a node or relationship has an internal id of 12345 and at some point that node or relationship is deleted, the id of 12345 becomes eligible for reuse by a future node or relationship. I believe it wise to assume the newly available id will be reused at some point in the future. This has the negative side effect of that Neo4j internal id’s are not considered “stable” and should not be used outside of your application.

As for an example of a new surrogate key, I would point you toward GraphAware’s neo4j-uuid project at https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-uuid. This Neo4j plugin can be used to automatically create a unique and stable UUID on all nodes and relationships that will not and can not be changed or updated.